# Line break on Product details

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Can someone be kind enough to help me with this problem as illustrated on the image ? I would like to be able to separate the product name , quantity, and price instead of being on one straight line. Your help would be much appreciated.
Many thanks  [image]

Comment: There's not enough information to answer this question. Are you using a plugin of some kind to generate this output? Do you have control of this page template? Do you have the means to modify it?

Comment: Hi yes im using the woo-commerce plugin. I have downloaded the entire site via ftp and have  control of the files . what im after is to apply line breaks on the product, price and cost on the text only email that's sent when an order is placed . Where do i need to apply the changes?

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Answer (score 0):

In your WordPress install, you'll go to 'WooCommerce/settings' and click the 'email' tab. From there you can see all of the emails that WooCommerce sends, and click on the title or gear icon to edit. The email format is determined by the template file that is listed at the bottom of the page. You can copy it to your theme to edit it. It requires some knowledge of PHP to make those modifications.

Depending on your comfort level with PHP, it may also be worth considering one of the many plugins that allow easy customization of WC emails.

Comment: I'm new at this and don't have great php skills. Would you have a cut n paste code i can use?